# Best practice to pre-load data in Coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to Prepopulate Core Data with Certain Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187497/way-to-prepopulate-core-data-with-certain-data)

I need an advice:  I'm start developing an app to collect expenses records (coredata backend).  I need to deploy the app with 3 preloaded entities (type, item and category) with relationship to record as follows:

"`Record` ‹‹--›`Type`"
"`Record` ‹‹--›`Item`"
"`Record` ‹‹--›`Category`"

I'm planning to insert/add a fake object in record entity just to respect record relationship between type, item and category; relationships are optional.

Which is the best way, in the long term, to load these lists with its relationships?. I've read several approaches, so I'm a little bit confused.

a) pre-populated database

b) Parsing xml /csv

c) inserting new objects at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `viewDidLoad`

All three lists are loaded once in app lifetime; however the app could need some updates every 3-6 months. `Item` has 200 records, `Type` has 3 records, and `Category` 30 records; all plain text.

I'm using XCode4.2 Bulid 4C199.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use a versioned database, with code that generates the latest version. It'll insert or update records and columns and such, supporting the update of any prior version to the latest, e.g.

```
if (noversiontable) {
    create tables;
    create defaults;
    set version to 1;
} else {
    get version;
}
if (version == 1) {
   updates to version 2;
   set version to 2;
}
if (version == 2) {
   updates to version 3;
   set version to 3;
}
saveVersion;
```

Sometimes I'm just adding columns, other times I'm deleting them or even altering data types and doing some kind of processing. For instance, I might have an address field and decide to add geocoding later. A version update would include processing existing records and running the geocode for them.

Answer (score 0):

While a pre-populated database is often easiest, you say that you have a requirement to update the data occasionally, and this leads me to believe that an import mechanism(your option b) would be worthwhile along with option c implemented with Matt H's versioning recommendation.  I prefer JSON to xml or csv for this purpose.  Its pretty easy to use KVC to copy each resulting dictionary into a core data object.